# Robot arm using "Solenoid"

Tags: dc-motor

I'm looking to create some kind of "pianoplaying" Pi robot.
I started to look into ways to create some kind of "arm" that can make a lateral movement and came across solenoids.I'm looking to create three arms and was thinking that I could use three solenoids for the movement of the arms and three solenoids to push the keys down on the piano.

What I need to know though is if it's possible to determine the range of motion for the solenoid using the GPIO library? Since it will be needed to determine which pianokey that should be pressed. If not is there a better simple way to create an arm that makes a lateral movement where you're able to decide the range of motion?

Comment: Solenoids are typically either "on" or "off" and thus are either fully extended or fully retracted. So this may not be suitable for your purpose. Some things to look at would be stepper motors and linear actuators.

Comment: @Leobd, You might like to consider linear servos: 
(1) Arduino Controlling Linear Servos   
https://ericeastwood.com/blog/12/cnc-controlling-linear-servos

(2) Youtube Controlling a mini Linear Servo - MadLittleMods 2014jan29
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj_3fwmUPNY

(3) Amazon GS1502 1.5g Linear Servo 0.08kgcm, 0.12sec/60° at 3V7 50-330Hz, 900-2100uS - US$15/pair
https://www.amazon.com/GoTeck-Analog-GS1502-Loading-Linear/dp/B06XCPRP5L

Answer (score 2):

A quick rule of thumb for if the GPIO is suitable for some type of input is to ask if the information you want is digital. That is, if the information you want is either on or off. Considering you're looking to track a variable position, the GPIO probably isn't suitable.

You might be able to use a linear encoder of some type and use the GPIO to count pulses and hence position. The general solution for variable input however is to use an analogue-to-digital converter like an MCP3008 combined with a potentiometer. (This is what an XBox or PlayStation controller uses for an 'analogue stick'.)